# Rendering primitive 2D shapes

Tags: c++, graphics

I am currently creating my own 3D renderer (think something like OpenGL). As a first step, I created a mini program below to render primitive 2D shapes essential to 3D graphics: points, lines, and triangles with z buffering.

I'm hoping for code review on three essential methods in the class `Display`

- `_DrawFilledTriangle` (see also `__DrawUpperFilledTriangle` and `__DrawLowerFilledTriangle`)
- `_DrawLine`
- `_PutPixel`

I'm not sure about parameters these methods should take. The current implementation looks ugly to me because x and y takes `int` values while z takes `double`. It is necessary so z buffering will work as intended. I tried `int` and it produces strange behavior. What are better parameter choices for these methods? I'm thinking about creating a `Point` struct but it will involve lots of moving and copying. I'm also quite concerned about their performance. Are there any way to speed execution?

Miscellaneous reviews are also welcome!

```
/* g++ primitives.cpp -o primitives -lSDL2 */

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

#include <Windows.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define ID_TIMER 1
#define UPDATE_INTERVAL 0

struct Colour
{
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t a;
};

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;
const int SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = 1;

const Colour RED{255, 0, 0, 255};
const Colour ORANGE{255, 127, 0, 255};
const Colour YELLOW{255, 255, 0, 255};
const Colour GREEN{0, 255, 0, 255};
const Colour BLUE{0, 0, 255, 255};
const Colour INDIGO{75, 0, 130, 255};
const Colour VIOLET{148, 0, 211, 255};

const Colour rainbow[7] = {
    RED,
    ORANGE,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    INDIGO,
    VIOLET
};

const double ZMAX = 10001.0;

class Display
{
public:
    Display(int width, int height);
    ~Display();

    void Create(HWND);
    void Update();
    void Paint();
    void CleanUp();
    void Destroy();
private:
    SDL_Window *wnd;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Texture *texture;

    int width;
    int height;

    std::vector<uint8_t> pixels;
    std::vector<double> zdepth;

    /* Coordinate system:
       x goes right starting from top left corner
       y goes down starting from top left corner
       z goes into page starting from top left corner
     */
    void _DrawFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, int x3, int y3, double z3, const Colour& colour);
    void __DrawUpperFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, int x3, int y3, double z3, const Colour& colour);
    void __DrawLowerFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, int x3, int y3, double z3, const Colour& colour);
    void _DrawLine(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, const Colour& colour);
    void _PutPixel(int x, int y, double z, const Colour& colour);

    bool _WithinBounds(int x, int y, double z); // for clipping
    void _Swap(int& x1, int& y1, double& z1, int& x2, int& y2, double& z2);
};

Display::Display(int width, int height)
  : width(width), height(height), pixels(width * height * 4), zdepth(width * height * 4)
{
    
}

Display::~Display()
{}

void Display::Create(HWND hWnd)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        std::exit(1);
    }

    wnd = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(hWnd);
    if (wnd == NULL)
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
        std::exit(1);
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(wnd, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't create renderer: %s", SDL_GetError());
        std::exit(1);
    }

    texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, width, height);
    if (texture == NULL)
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't create texture: %s", SDL_GetError());
        std::exit(1);
    }
}

void Display::Update()
{
    std::fill(zdepth.begin(), zdepth.end(), ZMAX);
/*
    int centerX = width / 2;
    int centerY = height / 2;

    float radius = 80.0;
    float dr = 20.0;

    double z = 0.0;
    double dz = 10.0;
    int middlez = 35.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        float angle = 0.0;

        while (angle < 360.0)
        {
            int x = centerX + int(radius * std::cos(angle));
            int y = centerY + int(radius * std::sin(angle));

            _DrawLine(centerX, centerY, middlez, x, y, z, rainbow[i]);

            angle += 1.0;
        }

        radius += dr;
        z += dz;
    }
*/
    _DrawFilledTriangle(10, 50, 10, 400, 100, 10, 290, 380, 10, RED);
    _DrawFilledTriangle(50, 350, 2, 130, 40, 20, 380, 200, 5, GREEN);
    /*
    _DrawLine(10, 10, 10, 380, 380, 10, GREEN);
    _DrawLine(10, 10, 1, 380, 380, 100, BLUE);
    _PutPixel(width - 1, height - 1, 0, RED);
    */
}

void Display::Paint()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, &pixels[0], width * 4);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Display::CleanUp()
{
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    texture = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(wnd);
    wnd = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

void Display::Destroy()
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}

// Nice reference: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/generalTriangle.png
void Display::_DrawFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, int x3, int y3, double z3, const Colour& colour)
{
    // Ensure that each vertex fits in the screen
    if (!_WithinBounds(x1, y1, z1) ||
        !_WithinBounds(x2, y2, z2) ||
        !_WithinBounds(x3, y3, z3))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Sort p1, p2, and p3 so that p1 < p2 < p3
    if (y2 < y1) { _Swap(x2, y2, z2, x1, y1, z1); }
    if (y3 < y1) { _Swap(x3, y3, z3, x1, y1, z1); }
    if (y3 < y2) { _Swap(x3, y3, z3, x2, y2, z2); }

    if (y2 == y3)
    {
        __DrawUpperFilledTriangle(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, colour);
    }
    else if (y1 == y2)
    {
        __DrawLowerFilledTriangle(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, colour);
    }
    else
    {
        // Find x4, y4, and z4 using similar triangles: (x3-x1)/(y3-y1)=(x4-x1)/(y4-y1), y4=y2
        int x4 = int(x1 + float(y2 - y1) * ((x3 - x1) / float(y3 - y1)));
        int y4 = y2;
        double z4;

        if (z1 > z3) // p1 is farther than p3
        {
            z4 = z3 + double(y3 - y4) * ((z1 - z3) / double(y3 - y1));
        }
        else
        {
            z4 = z3 - double(y3 - y4) * ((z3 - z1) / double(y3 - y1));
        }

        __DrawUpperFilledTriangle(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x4, y4, z4, colour);
        __DrawLowerFilledTriangle(x2, y2, z2, x4, y4, z4, x3, y3, z3, colour);
    }
}

void Display::__DrawUpperFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, int x3, int y3, double z3, const Colour& colour)
{
    float dy1 = std::fabs(y2 - y1);
    float dy2 = std::fabs(y3 - y1);

    float curx1 = x1;
    float curx2 = x1 + 0.5;
    float xinc1 = (x2 - x1) / dy1;
    float xinc2 = (x3 - x1) / dy2;

    double curz1 = z1;
    double curz2 = z1 + 0.5;
    double zinc1 = (z2 - z1) / dy1;
    double zinc2 = (z3 - z1) / dy2;

    for (int y = y1; y <= y2; y++)
    {
        _DrawLine((int) curx1, y, curz1, (int) curx2, y, curz2, colour);

        curx1 += xinc1;
        curx2 += xinc2;
        curz1 += zinc1;
        curz2 += zinc2;
    }
}

void Display::__DrawLowerFilledTriangle(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, int x3, int y3, double z3, const Colour& colour)
{
    float dy1 = std::fabs(y3 - y1);
    float dy2 = std::fabs(y3 - y2);

    float curx1 = x3;
    float curx2 = x3 + 0.5;
    float xinc1 = (x3 - x1) / dy1;
    float xinc2 = (x3 - x2) / dy2;

    double curz1 = z3;
    double curz2 = z3 + 0.5;
    double zinc1 = (z3 - z1) / dy1;
    double zinc2 = (z3 - z2) / dy2;

    for (int y = y3; y > y1; y--)
    {
        _DrawLine((int) curx1, y, curz1, (int) curx2, y, curz2, colour);

        curx1 -= xinc1;
        curx2 -= xinc2;
        curz1 -= zinc1;
        curz2 -= zinc2;
    }
}

// Adapted from https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/wiki/Lesson-1:-Bresenham%E2%80%99s-Line-Drawing-Algorithm
void Display::_DrawLine(int x1, int y1, double z1, int x2, int y2, double z2, const Colour& colour)
{
    if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && std::fabs(z1 - z2) < 1e-4)
    {
        _PutPixel(x1, y1, z1, colour);
        return;
    }

    bool steep = false;

    if (std::abs(x1 - x2) < std::abs(y1 - y2))
    {
        _Swap(x1, x2, z1, y1, y2, z1);
        steep = true;
    }

    if (x1 > x2)
    {
        _Swap(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2);
    }

    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    double dz = z2 - z1;

    int derrY = std::abs(dy) * 2;
    int errY = 0;
    int y = y1;
    int yinc = y2 > y1 ? 1 : -1;

    double z = z1;
    double zinc = dz / std::fabs(dx);

    if (steep)
    {
        for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
        {
            _PutPixel(y, x, z, colour);

            errY += derrY;
            if (errY > dx)
            {
                y += yinc;
                errY -= dx * 2;
            }

            z += zinc;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
        {
            _PutPixel(x, y, z, colour);

            errY += derrY;
            if (errY > dx)
            {
                y += yinc;
                errY -= dx * 2;
            }

            z += zinc;
        }
    }
}

void Display::_PutPixel(int x, int y, double z, const Colour& colour)
{
    int offset = y * width * 4 + x * 4;

    if (zdepth[offset] > z)
    {
        zdepth[offset] = z;
        pixels[offset] = colour.b;
        pixels[offset + 1] = colour.g;
        pixels[offset + 2] = colour.r;
        pixels[offset + 3] = colour.a;
    }
}

bool Display::_WithinBounds(int x, int y, double z)
{
    return x >= 0 && x < width &&
           y >= 0 && y < height &&
           z >= 0.0;
}

void Display::_Swap(int& x1, int& y1, double& z1, int& x2, int& y2, double& z2)
{
    int tmpX = x1;
    int tmpY = y1;
    double tmpZ = z1;

    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;
    z1 = z2;

    x2 = tmpX;
    y2 = tmpY;
    z2 = tmpZ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static Display app(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        app.Create(hWnd);

        if(!SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, UPDATE_INTERVAL, NULL))
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "Could not set timer!", "errYor", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            PostQuitMessage(1);
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
    {
        app.Update();
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
        break;
    }
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        app.Paint();
        break;
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        app.CleanUp();
        KillTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        app.Destroy();
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const TCHAR szClassName[] = TEXT("MyClass");

    WNDCLASS wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;
    RECT rcClient;
    UINT style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE; // no maximize box and resizing

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Window Registration Failed!"), TEXT("errYor!"),
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    rcClient.left = 0;
    rcClient.top = 0;
    rcClient.right = SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR;
    rcClient.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT * SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR;

    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rcClient, style, TRUE, 0);

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szClassName,
        TEXT("SDLWin1"),
        style,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
        rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Window Creation Failed!"), TEXT("errYor!"),
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Output

[image: out]

Answer (score 8):

- Your use of underscores to prefix methods is not a good idea since
  they are reserved.
- The lack of comments through out the code mean
  that it is more difficult to read than it should be.
- You should look at making variables and arguments const where they can be.
- Use of a struct/class to amalgamate the three co-ordinate values for a point would help.
- You might want to look at cleaning the level 3 warnings (at least) up from the compiler.  There should be some about implicit casting (double to float) and C Style casts.
- In __DrawLowerFilledTriangles you are doing a std::fabs() where the parameter is an int.  I *feel* this might be a performance hit, it *might* be better to use abs and then cast to a float.  If you are going to use this function a lot it might make a difference.
- Again this is just a feeling, it might be more performant in _PutPixel to write the colour as a 32bit uint rather than 4 8bit uints.  So you could add an operator to the Colour class that wrote it to a uint32 in the bgra order using the bitwise shift operator.
- I've just read your comment about the Point.  If you use const ref arguments to you function and emplace on your vectors you should be OK about moving and copying.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! When amalgamating coordinates, I want all of them take the same type (either int or double). But if I use double for x and y, there will be lots of conversions to int. I wonder if it will make the program slow.

Comment: I've always wondered about double/fp pixel co-ordinates.  How many screens let you print to 1/2 a pixel?  You could use a template and let the compiler do all the work, you code could/should be agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Small things

- The first line comment appears to be instructions on how to compile. If you plan on expanding the project beyond this, maybe it is worth making compilation commands into a Makefile.
- Don't leave around commented-out code if you can. Refactor to demo functions if they do demo functionality.
- You don't have to implement swaps with a temp variable in c++ because we have `std::swap`.
- Maybe it's worth having a Triangle class instead of taking in lots of arguments for triangle drawing. Stylistically I don't like functions with 10 arguments. It's more natural to represent a triangle as 3 individual vertices.
- For a Point struct, the compiler should be able to figure out when to move or copy with using const refs. And I would guess it's not a performance issue versus the computations for drawing but that would be revealed through profiling.
- If you do a lot of data shuffling, maybe it is faster to be able to access the 4 8-bit channels as a single 32-bit value in a [union with type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664848/unions-and-type-punning) or have proper getters and setters. This should be profiled too.